# Unable to access jarfile web: java -jar ./build/libs/*****-all.jar

Tags: kotlin, heroku, ktor

This is my first time deploying a ktor app to Heroku and i have been getting the error
Unable to access jarfile

Below is my build.gradle.kts file.

I have been trying to go though documentation and other stackoverflow pages for help but could not figure what i wrong. I able to genarate the .jar file and build sucessfully on Heroku. I have attached the screenshot from the Heroku page, which shows the jar file being deployed in dynos. But still get the above error. Any help will be great.

```
import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.openapi.vfs.StandardFileSystems.jar

val ktor_version: String by project
val kotlin_version: String by project
val logback_version: String by project
val exposed_version: String by project
val postgres_version: String by project
val hikari_version: String by project

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.22"
    id("io.ktor.plugin") version "2.3.8"
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.9.22"
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "7.1.2"
}

group = "com.schoolcircle"
version = "0.0.1"

application {
    mainClass.set("com.schoolcircle.ApplicationKt")
}
tasks {
    withType<Jar> {
        manifest {
            attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.schoolcircle.ApplicationKt"
        }
    }
}
//tasks.shadowJar {
//    manifest {
//        attributes["Main-Class"] = application.mainClass.get()
//    }
//}


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url = uri("https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/exposed")
    }
    maven { url = uri("https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor") }
    maven {
        url = uri("https://repo.spring.io/release")
    }
    google()
}

tasks {
    create("stage").dependsOn("installDist")
}
tasks.test {
    enabled = false
}
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {
    if (this.hasTask("stage")) {
        tasks.test {
            enabled = false
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-auth-jvm")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-core-jvm")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-auth-jwt-jvm")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-sessions-jvm")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-netty-jvm")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-locations:$kotlin_version")
    implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:$logback_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-content-negotiation:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-jackson:$ktor_version")
    testImplementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-tests-jvm")
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlin_version")
    testImplementation ("io.ktor:ktor-server-tests:$ktor_version")

    implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-core:$exposed_version")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-dao:$exposed_version")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-jdbc:$exposed_version")
    implementation("org.postgresql:postgresql:$postgres_version")
    implementation("com.zaxxer:HikariCP:$hikari_version")

}
```

And my Procfile is
`web: java -jar ./build/libs/school-backend-all.jar`

[image]

Comment: Are you able to run your application with the same `java -jar ...` command locally? If so, the problem is probably due to the incorrect path to the JAR file.

Comment: Locally it runs. It is able to access the jar file. What can cause the path to gop wrong on heroku ?

Comment: I would check that the directories `build` and `libs` exist, there is a JAR file in the `libs` directory and the current working directory is correct.

Comment: how can check that on heroku, i do not see any option. And their support has left me stranded saying this is out of their scope of support.

Comment: Can you execute an arbitrary shell command on Heroku?

Comment: finally after a lot of debugging i found out that in my .gitignore file had the build folder added, which was preventing the jar file to be uplaoded to heroku. I removed that and it went past that error.

Answer (score 0):

Check the .gitignore file, if the build folder is added there, it can be a possibility that it may be added there and due to this the jar file is not able to be uploaded to heroku in the first place.